# javascript object literal dynamic key SyntaxError

Tags: javascript, object, syntax

What is wrong with this expression?

```
['a', 'b'].map((x) => {[x]:x})
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to wrap your `{}` in `()`, or it will be interpreted as the body of a function:

```
['a', 'b'].map((x) => ({[x]: x }))
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. As a side note, for clarity, I often wrap the returned object like this: 
`['a', 'b'].map((x) => Object({[x]: x}))`

Answer (score 4):

You have enclosed the return value with `()`

```js
let result = ['a', 'b'].map((x) => ({[x]: x}));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 4):

whenever you return object from arrow functions you wrap them in paranthesis

`['a', 'b'].map((x) => ({[x]:x}))`